# Is it possible to store ETH in a variable, not a contract itself?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether

I commonly see ETH being paid to a contract itself:

```
payable(payeeAddress).transfer(amount);
```

But, is it also possible to store an ETH amount in a variable?:

```
struct Payment {
    uint payment;
    uint256 price;
    uint256 tokenId;
    address seller;
}

mapping (address => Payment) private _payment;

function pay(address id) public payable {
    require(
        _payment[id].price > 0,
        "Not for sale."
    );

    require(
        msg.value == _payment[id].price,
        "Incorrect price."
    );   
    
    // store ETH in a variable
    _payment[id].payment = msg.value;
    
    // transfer the token
    uint256 tokenId = _payment[id].tokenId;
    address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
    _transfer(owner, msg.sender, tokenId);
    _payment[id].price = 0; // not for sale anymore
    
    emit PaymentMade(msg.sender, msg.value, id);
}
```

The ETH is to be withdrawn in a separate transaction:

```swift
function withdraw(address id) public {
    require(
        msg.sender == _payment[id].seller, "Not authorized."
    );
    
    payable(msg.sender).transfer(_payment[id].payment);
}
```

I'm not including the value transfer within the `pay` method because I'm under the impression it's safer to have the payee withdraw the fund.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ether is always stored in the contract itself, but nothing stops you from storing the amount also in a variable. This is quite typical in contracts which have multiple people sending it Ethers and you need to keep records of who sent and how much. But you can't prevent the Ether from being in the balance of the contract - unless you send it somewhere else for safekeeping.

Comment: Is it also true about the statement that it's safer to have the payee withdraw the funds to their wallet as opposed to have the payer 1) transfer a token and 2) transfer the fund to the payee's wallet? Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: On average, it's safer to let them withdraw